# Find out where a special character exists in a dataframe using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, data-analysis

I have a iris dataset where I have added some special characters like '?' , '@' and other such values. The question is I need to find out the row number in which I am finding these special character.
`re.findall('?',str(data))`

Comment: You can use the [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use.

```
df=df[~df['word'].str.contains('|'.join(BAD_CHARS))
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.